# Whats the use of $parameter_type parameter in this pdo->quote() method in php?

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PHP PDO and learning about the `PDO->quote()` method. The second parameter just confused me. Can anyone tell what's the point and use of the second parameter in following method?

```
PDO->quote($string,$parameter_type)
```

Reference Link: [PDO::Quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question !!!

Comment: In practice, you should almost _never_ use PDO::quote(). It is almost always much more appropriate to to use `prepare()/bindParam()/execute()` than to build a string with `quote()`.

Comment: It's not the answer - and that is why it was posted as a comment.

Comment: Ok fine i will use prepare/bind and execute, right. But can you tell me what is the use of the second parameter in PDO->quote() method ?

Comment: _Provides a data type hint for drivers that have alternate quoting styles._  - some databases may require that different value types (strings vs ints, vs binary etc) have different quoting methods. Not every database depends on that ability. That parameter just specifies what data type the value should be passed into SQL as, if it must be differently quoted..

Comment: ^ shock it does what the manual says it does.

Comment: Please provide your explanation as answer and i will accept it then !!!

Comment: please ! stop !! banging !!! on !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `PDO::Quote()` `$parameter_type` the manual states:

> Provides a data type hint for drivers that have alternate quoting styles.

With a default of `PDO::PARAM_STR` (Represents the SQL CHAR, VARCHAR, or other string data type.).  Other values can be found here [PDO Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants).